# References in fluent hibernate mapping seems dosnt work correctly

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using fluent hibernate 1.2.0.712 and nhibernate 3.2.0.4000 in my mvc project as an OR mapper, the problem is :
this is my oJob object:

```
public class Job{

    virtual public Enquiry Enquiry { get; set; }
    virtual public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

and this is Enquiry:

```
public class Enquiry {

virtual public long Id { get; set; }
}
```

and here is JobMap:

```
 public  class JobMap: ClassMap<Job>
{
   public JobMap()
   {
       Schema("dbo");

       Id(p => p.Id)
           .Column("Id");

       References(p => p.Enquiry);
    }
}
```

i expect that each job has exactly one enquiry

but sometimes that i check sql server i see there are some records in job table with different ids that all have the same enquiryid

and i checked it many times and dont know when exactly it happens, what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You must change your mapping : change

```
References(p => p.Enquiry);
```

by

```
HasOne(p => p.Enquiry);
```

Comment: it doesnt persist any thing to data base, i think hasone needs references on the other side of relation

Comment: Yes, it is… Don't you have a one-to-one relation ?

Comment: not exactly,, the enquiry object does not know anything of job object

Comment: OK… Your mappings are correct. I think you just need to add a unique constraint in the Job table : try to replace References(p => p.Enquiry) by References(p => p.Enquiry).Unique(). With this new constraint you won't be able to have two Job rows with the same EnquiryId.

Comment: even by adding References(p => p.Enquiry).Unique() nothing has changed, and till now i can see records with the same enquiryid

Comment: Adding References(p => p.Enquiry).Unique() with an existing database is not enough… You must also create a unique constraint in your database, or simply recreate your database with Fluent NHibernate, which will create the schema - and the constraint - for you.